# How to target html elements when logged into DNN

Tags: html, css, dotnetnuke

Silly question and I hope I just overlooked this. In Sitefinity, once you are logged in, there is a wrapping div which one can use to target certain html tags ONLY when you are logged in.

I am not seeing anything like this in DNN and was wondering if someone knows of a solution to this please?

What I would like, is something like this:

```
[div class="dnn-logged-in"] 
   [div class="my-content-wrapper"] 
      [div class="elements-i-would-like-to-show-or-hide] 
         Hide or show this if I am logged in or not 
      [/div] 
   [/div] 
[/div]
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In DotNetNuke this is controlled by permissions, which can be assigned to pages or to individual modules (specific content).  By default, new pages will have VIEW permissions for "All Users", and new content created on the page will inherit that permission.

To change this, select the settings for the specific content, un-check the "Inherit View Permissions from Page.  This will enable the check-boxes for all the various roles.  Then simply ensure that All Users is un-selected, and instead select "Registered Users".  This will make the content visibleto any user who is logged into the site.

This is a super powerful permission model which actually controls the rendering, rather than just obscuring visibility.

Comment: Thanks Scott! What I am after though is the ability to isolate certain html elements when a person is logged in as opposed to when they are logged out. Dnn has a nasty habit for example of naming their control panel footer ".footer" which is a universal class used by most people for the footer. What I will do in future though, is add my own wrapping div and target all my elements like this: .my-site .footer {do:stuff;} or .my-site .header {do:stuff;}. Else I am going to keep messing up the cpanel of DNN. Hopefully DNN6 sorts this out :)

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing James.  My client wants the top navigation centered if logged in and aligned right otherwise.  So far I'm not seeing any way to indicate the logged in status.  Bleh.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is a fairly uncommon task because this type of logic is generally handled on the server side and not the client side. This is because you generally don't want to increase the client payload any more than you need to - and if the user isn't logged in - they'll never need this content. In addition there are obviously security implications if working with sensitive data - as the information is easily viewable in the underlying markup.

All disclaimers aside, If you do want to do this, I think the best solution would be to just make site work just like you're used to in Sitefinity. In DNN you would create a container that contains the appropriate logic. A container wraps each module, and within the container you have the opportunity to write any code (server or client) to make your container dynamic.

For this brute force example I modified the "Invisible.ascx" container that ships with the DarkKnight skin in DNN 6:

```
<%@ Control language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="DotNetNuke.UI.Containers.Container" %>

<%
  var isLoggedIn = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
  if (isLoggedIn)
  {
%>
<div class="dnn-logged-in">
<% } %>

<div class="Invisible"><div id="ContentPane" runat="server"></div></div>

<% if (isLoggedIn) { %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

This will yield the following HTML when not authenticated:

```
<div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML DnnModule-364">
  <a name="364"></a>
  <div class="Invisible">
    <div id="dnn_ctr364_ContentPane">
      [Dynamic Content Here]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this when you are authenticated:

```
<div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML DnnModule-364">
  <a name="364"></a>
  <div class="dnn-logged-in">
    <div class="Invisible">
      <div id="dnn_ctr364_ContentPane">
      [Dynamic Content Here]
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want this logic everywhere, I'd just enhance each of the containers that you're currently using with this type of logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SkinObject to do so in dnn. Login skin object will help you showing a Login/ Logout OR Regiter, User Skin object will help you show the currently logged in user. You can use any style and div you want.

Comment: Thanks lakhlaniprashant. What do you mean by a SkinObject other than the new skins I am creating? Is this a setting you refer to?

Comment: Skin objects are special user controls in dnn that you can use in dnn skins and modules as per your requirement. there are many in built skin objects available, see this for more:http://lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com/2009/06/dotnetnuke-skin-objects.html